# Angularjs, how change color of multiple items in div

Tags: angularjs

I would like to ask, how to change color of clicked items in div in Angularjs:

```
<div ng-repeat="answers in answer track by $index" 
ng-click="addToAnswers(currentPage,$index)">{{answers}}</div>
```

This is for quiz answers.
like here: [a link](http://jsfiddle.net/xk6Ut/60/)
"jquery click to toggle", but i would like not to use jquery.

Comment: could you update what `addToAnswers` method does? and currentPage parameter  stands for?

Answer (score 3):

1st thing please correct `answers in answer` to `answer in answers`. You could have `isChecked` property on each `element` of `answers`

```
<div ng-repeat="answer in answers track by $index" 
   ng-class="answer.isChecked? 'red': 'green'"
   ng-click="addToAnswers(currentPage,$index);answer.isChecked != answer.isChecked">
   {{answer}}
</div>

Selected Answers{{ answers | filter: {isChecked: true}}}
```

**CSS**

```
.red {
   background-color: red;
}

.green {
   background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: missing set of interploation braces for string?

Comment: @charlietfl curly brace doesn't required there for expression..Thanks for heads up man. :)

Comment: @charlietfl where, you mean to say in `ng-class`?

Comment: You can use ternary in ng-class? I thought it was only `class1: condition1, class2: condition2`

Comment: @RichardHamilton yes you can use it in `ng-class`, basically it accepts expression **OR** you could supply a JSON which will have various class with expression like `{class1: condition1, class2: condition2}`

Comment: @RichardHamilton expression can return string or object

Comment: Still, color doesn't change from green after clicking on answer .

Comment: @thinkmore now try updated css..I had wrong color value in `.green` class :p

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `ng-class`.

In your `ng-click` function, you will want to set the scope's `clicked` variable to true. That way, you can show the red class, when it's been clicked, and the green class otherwise.

```
$scope.clicked = false;
$scope.addToAnswers = function(page, index) {
    page.clicked = true;
});

<div ng-repeat="answers in answer track by $index" 
ng-click="addToAnswers(currentPage,$index)"
ng-class="{'back-red': currentPage.clicked, 'back-green': !currentPage.clicked}">{{answers}}</div>

.back-red { background-color: red; }
```

Comment: will add class to all items, not instance specific one

Comment: yep, that's why conditional classes. I'm pretty sure this will work. will test it out in plunker

Comment: missing the point ... same `$scope.clicked` for all items so clicking one will toggle all

Comment: I want to toggle color on/off on click, like i have 4 answers: 1.a       2.b              3.c        4.d        if i click on one of those answers i only want that answer color to change.

Comment: Since we're iterating over each answers, we simply have to set the clicked property of every answer? So adding answer.clicked should solve this?